# How to prioritize some records using Java Comapartor

Tags: java, database, sorting, comparator

I am using comparator to sort the results in the following way-

```
Comparator.comparing(Parent::getName)
                .thenComparing(Parent::getRollNumber)
                .thenComparing(Parent::getSubName))
```

I have usecase that if Name is "Swati", then I have to always show that record at top and other in ascending order.

Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: Is result of `getName` a `String` object?

Comment: yes it is a String object

Comment: You'll need to use a custom comparator first in the chain that makes "Swati" less than everything else. One way would be `Comparing.compare(Parent::getName, (a, b) -> a.equals(b) ? 0 : a.equals("Swati") 
? -1 : b.equals("Swati") ? 1 : a.compareTo(b)). ...`. I don't have a way to check this, but it ought to be close.

Comment: Do you mean Comparator.comapre()?

Comment: Yes. Sorry.  Actually it's `Comparator.compare(...)`. Typing faster than thinking is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the way to resolve the problem

```
@Override 

public int compare (Parent a, Parent b) { 

if (a != null && b != null) { 

if (a.getName() == null && b.getName()  == null)  

 {  return 0;} 

 if (a.getName() == null)  

        {return -1;} 

if (b.getName() == null)  

        {return 1;} 

//comparing Swati with others 

if (a.getName(). equals("Swati") && b.getName(). equals("Swati")) { 

return 0; 

} else if (a.getName(). equals("Swati")) { 

return -1; 

} else if (b.getName(). equals("Swati")) { 

return 1; 

} 

// Comparing Parent other than Swati 

int compareResult = a.getName().compareTo(b.getName()); 

return compareResult; 

} 

return 0; 

}
```

Another Solution Using Java 8 Comparator

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(Student::getName, (a, b) -> a == null || b == null ? 0 : a.equals(b) ? 0 : a.equals("Swati") ? -1 : b.equals("Swati") ? 1 : a.compareTo(b))));
```

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).